# plese help me to solve Error main.lua:50: attempt to index global 'coin' (a nil value)

Tags: lua, love2d

how do i use the Table coin in the function love.graphic.rettangle without making it global? I declare the table in a love.update() function (I don't know if anything changes)

```
if math.random() < 0.01 then --math.rand restituisce numeri da 0 a 1 (la usiamo come probabilità)
 local coin = {}
     coin.h = 80
     coin.w = 80
     coin.x = math.random(0, 800 - coin.w)
     coin.y = math.random(0, 800 - coin.h)
         table.insert(coins, coin)-- inseriamo nella table coins il table coin appena creato
 end
end
function love.draw()
--[[love.graphics.setBackgroundColor( 255, 150, 150)
love.graphics.setColor(255, 0, 0)]]
love.graphics.setColor(255, 0, 0)
love.graphics.rectangle("fill", player.x, player.y, player.w, player.h)
love.graphics.setColor(255, 255, 0)
 for i=1, #coins, 1 do
   love.graphics.rectangle("fill", coin.x, coin.y, coin.w, coin.w, coin.h)
 end
end
```

Comment: You wrote `coin` instead of `coins[i]`

Comment: if you post an error message with a line number, please post the code from the beginning or add a comment that tells everyone which line is line 50. that way we don't have to read through all your code. that's the reason why error messages come with line numbers btw. so you know where to look for the error cause.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i=1, #coins, 1 do
   love.graphics.rectangle("fill", coin.x, coin.y, coin.w, coin.w, coin.h)
 end
```

In the scope of your function `love.draw`, `coin` is a nil value.

`coin` is local to the followin if statement and hence cannot be used outside.

```
if math.random() < 0.01 then --math.rand restituisce numeri da 0 a 1 (la usiamo come probabilità)
 local coin = {}
     coin.h = 80
     coin.w = 80
     coin.x = math.random(0, 800 - coin.w)
     coin.y = math.random(0, 800 - coin.h)
         table.insert(coins, coin)-- inseriamo nella table coins il table coin appena creato
 end
```

But as you inserted the local `coin` into `coins` you can access each coin by indexing `coins` if `draw.love` is in its scope.

So instead of the for loop above write

```
for i=1, #coins, 1 do  -- the third parameter defaults to 1 so for i = #coins do is enough
   local coin = coins[i]
   love.graphics.rectangle("fill", coin.x, coin.y, coin.w, coin.w, coin.h)
 end
```

As coins is a sequence you could also use a generic for loop with `ipairs`

You probably have a `coin.w` to many btw.

```
for _, coin in ipairs(coins) do
  love.graphics.rectangle("fill", coin.x, coin.y, coin.w, coin.h)
end
```